# How to tell if an EventSource (SSE) is still open and keep it persistent?

Tags: javascript, perl, server-sent-events, mojolicious

I have an area in my page that emits an event every time someone changes a certain field in a database. Now, the event seems to fire for a little while, but after a certain period of idle time I no longer get broadcast messages when the column has been changed.

I have Firebug, but I am not entirely sure how to make sure the connection is still open. If I look at Firebug it says, "CLOSED: 2, CONNECTING: 0, OPEN: 1, readyState: 0" but it seems to say this regardless of whether events are firing (emitting, displaying). I need this SSE to be persistent, which I thought would be accomplished by disabling the timeout in Mojolicious, but does not seem to be the case.

My questions are as follows: A) How do I tell if the connection is still active? and B) How do I keep the connection persistent for as long as a user is viewing the page?

The relevant Mojolicious code is here:

```
package Ownership;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojo::EventEmitter';

sub newowner {
    my $self = shift;
    my ( $owner, $location ) = @_;

    my $timestamp = localtime(time);

    $self->emit( newowner => "[$timestamp] - 
        $owner has taken ownership of $location" );
}

package main;

my $ownership = Ownership->new;
get '/events' => sub {
    my $self = shift;

    Mojo::IOLoop->stream( $self->tx->connection )->timeout(0);

    $self->res->headers->content_type('text/event-stream');

    my $cb = $ownership->on(
        newowner => sub {
            my ( $ownership, $message ) = @_;
            $self->write("event:newowner\ndata: $message\n\n");
        }
     );

     $self->on(
        finish => sub {
            my $self = shift;
            $ownership->unsubscribe( newowner => $cb );
        }
     );
};
```

And here's the Javascript from my index.html.ep:

```
var events = new EventSource('<%= url_for 'events' %>');
events.addEventListener('newowner', function(event) {
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + event.data + '<br />';
}, false);
```